# Background Image is Hiding Header and Navigation

Tags: image, background

I added a BG images to the body of a html document. after config of size and other properties, the head and list have just removed themselves.  I looked at the webpage index file via web inspector, and they are physically there. just not displayed.

and ideas why this behavior would happen?

if you guys need to see the code just ask.

thanks in advance...

~Ryozaki

Comment: ..can we see the code?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

<title> Zach Williams </title>

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<div id="header">
<h1> Zach Williams </h1>
</div>
<body>
<div id="bg">
<img src="images/background.jpg" alt="Oregon">
</div>
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Photo</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Web</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Media</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>

Comment: it would be helpful if you could create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), so that we can also see what styles you are applying, this alone doesn't help much. Also if that truly is your markup, `title` needs to be inside of `head`, you are missing your closing `head` tag, and you have a div outside of your `body` tag.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of HTML issues...

- Your `<title>` needs to go inside of your `<head></head>` tags.
- You can't put `<div>` tags between your `<head></head>` tags.
- You're missing a closing `</head>` tag

Try this:

- Insert a `<head>` tag before your `<title>` tag.
- Then change your `<head>` tag after `</title>` to `</head>`

Comment: im making a fiddle so you guys can see the code a littel better. ill post a link in three seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You need to review your `positioning` rules

If you have an element positioned as `absolute` it will overlay any elements below it, unless you position the elements below to `absolute` as well or position them to `relative` with a `z-index` greater than 0.

But for your particular case you don't need to add `absolute` positioning to your image, just leave it as `static` and it solves your problems.

here is the your css code revised and works (per as your Fiddle):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FlexDisplay-Thin';
    src: url('mywebsite/fonts/FlexDisplay-Thin');
    src: local('?'), url('FlexDisplay-Thin') format('ot'), url("FlexDisplay-Thin") format('truetype'), url(FlexDisplay-Thin) format('avg');
}

h1
{   
    font-family: 'FlexDisplay-Thin', arial, sans-serif;
}

#bg {   
    position: static;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
}
#bg img {   
    position: static;
    margin: auto;
    min-width: 50%
    min-height: 50%;
    z-index:0
}

#navigation{
    width: 550px;
    height: 35px;
    font-size; 16px;
    font-family: 'FlexDisplay-Thin', arial,sans-serif;
    text-align; center;
}
```

Comment: thanks a mil... i just used to code. what does the z-index define.. im kinda still learing @RCorrie

Comment: z-index is used for absolute and relative positioned elements. It defines wether an element appears over or below another. So for example: Element A has z-index:9; Element B has z-index:0; and Element C has z-index:-9;

Element A will be over Element B and both of these will be over Element C.

But they must be set positioned to either relative or absolute.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp they explain it better than me